# How to look up values from another dataset with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow

I got 2 csv datasources. I need to doing some data formatting before building a model.

===============================================

**Datasource 1:** Plant.csv

The features of different plants.

```
PlantID, INT /
PlantName, STR /
Color, STR / 
Size, FLOAT /
Cost, FLOAT /
Category, INT /
Weight, FLOAT /
Expire, INT /
STATUS, INT
```

**Datasource 2:** [201601.csv, 201602.csv, 201603.csv....]

Monthly Order Sales of Plants

```
PlantID, INT /
SalesPerson, STR /
Date, DATETIME /
Qty, INT /
Price, FLOAT /
Gardener, STR /
Package1, BOOL /
Package2, BOOL /
Package3, BOOL
```

===============================

Now I am going to join those files into a single file like this:

```
PlantID, INT /
PlantName, STR /
Color, STR / 
Size, FLOAT /
Cost, FLOAT /
Category, INT /
Weight, FLOAT /
Expire, INT /
STATUS, INT /
SalesPerson, STR /
Date, DATETIME /
Qty, INT /
Price, FLOAT /
Gardener, STR /
Package1, BOOL /
Package2, BOOL /
Package3, BOOL
```

which look up PlantID as the key.

There are millions of sales records each month.

Could anybody advise how to make it with `tensorflow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow is not for joining databases. If you really want to do it in python you can use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv('Plant.csv')
df1.set_index(['PlantID'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('201601.csv')
df2.set_index(['PlantID'])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

**Tensorflow** is for creating computational graphs and then running them efficiently. In general it will assume that the inputs to this graph are already a numpy array.

**pandas** was made to work with relational data inside python as you would in a relational database. Although if you have the option of working inside an actual relational database with a query language this is still more computationally efficient than pandas.